# How to setup PPPoE connection on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: system-settings

I've been using Ubuntu for over 10 years. But I can't find the PPPoE setup menu for the first time ever. Do I need to install an additional package?

My Settings Looks like now:
[image: screenshot of settings app]